# Clear field value from Anguilla framework

Tags: 2011, gui-extensions

It looks like something pretty easy, but I can't find how to do this.
I need to clear value for some field via javascript. It could be regular text , component link , keyword or dropdown field type. I have following code:

```
var field = $display.getView().properties.controls.fieldBuilder.getField("some_field");
field.clear();// I need somesting like this
```

Is it possible to do this in elegant way or I have to look into DOM and clear it manually separately for each field type?

Comment: Do you mean Anguilla? Angular-js is something completely different.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but `FieldBuilder` has a `clearContents()` method described in the documentation. Would that work for you?

Comment: @NunoLinhares Yes, you are right. My mistake, I meant Anguilla.

Comment: @AlvinReyes Unfortunately I can't see such method within my FieldBuilder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had quick look in the code for the component dialog and found the following snippet that should help you resolve your problem:

```
Tridion.FieldBuilder.FieldTypeHandlers.MultiLineTextField.prototype.setValues = function MultiLineTextField$setValues(values)
{
    var changed = false;
    if (values && this.properties.input)
    {
        if (values.length > 1)
        {
            throw Error("This field allows a single value only.");
        }
        else if (values.length == 1)
        {
            var value = values[0];
            if (this.properties.input.value != value)
            {
                changed = true;
                this.properties.input.value = value;
            }
        }
        else if (this.properties.input.value.length > 0)
        {
            changed = true;
            this.properties.input.value = "";
        }
    }
    if (changed)
    {
        this.fireChange();
    }
};
```

I'm assuming for other field types such as SingleLineTextField the setting/clearing of the value is the same, or if there are differences it wouldn't be too much work to write a generic function to clear your value based on the field type.

Comment: Your answer is correct. In most cases setValues([]) clearing value. However there are some issue with KeywordField type. For some reason settings property is not set for input control. I've done short workaround for it. So finally method looks like:  `function clear(field){  if(field.getTypeName() == "Tridion.FieldBuilder.FieldTypeHandlers.KeywordField")  field.getInputControl().settings = {};  field.setValues([]);  }`

Comment: hi @vitaly yeah as i mentioned i suspect different field types will vary in solution.  glad you got it working :)

Comment: maybe also post your method or code snippet that deals with these various code types for all :)

Answer (score 4):

OK. So, I post my final method appereance:

```
var clear = function(field) {
    if (field.getTypeName() == "Tridion.FieldBuilder.FieldTypeHandlers.EmbeddedSchemaField") {
        var fieldDefinitions = field.properties.input.properties.fieldsDefinition.children;
        $.each(fieldDefinitions, function(i, fieldDefinition) {
            var fieldName = fieldDefinition.firstChild.firstChild.data;
            var currField = field.getField(fieldName);
            clear(currField);
        });
    } else {
        if (field.getTypeName() == "Tridion.FieldBuilder.FieldTypeHandlers.KeywordField")
            field.getInputControl().settings = {};
        field.setValues([]);
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, I didn't find more elegant way to get all fields from embeddable field (`field.getInputControl().getFields()` doesn't work and always returns empty array). Anyway above function works for me perfectly